# Передача цвета из метода и использование его для фона, анимация

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть метод, который должен на основании значения выдать цвет, а потом надо в коде xaml на wpf к фону привязать этот метод, отдав ему значение Labela, таким образом, если лабел.текст=1, то его фон будет таким-то, а если 2, то другим. Подскажите пожалуйста, как такое сделать?

```
 public Color PoluchitCvet(string vhodnoeznachenie)
        {
            switch (vhodnoeznachenie)
            {
                case "1":
                    return  [здесь цвет1]// кстати, цвет не могу задать здесь
                    break;
                case "2":
                    return  [здесь цвет2]
                    break;;
                case "3":
                    return  [здесь цвет3]
                    break;
                default:
                    return  [здесь цвет4] 
                    break;
            }
        }
```

И как сделать так, чтобы при изменении значения метки, например, плавно менялся цвет, т.е. сделать анимацию? Например, было значение 2 [цвет фона 2] и вдруг значение метки поменялось на 1, чтобы цвет фона изменился плавно, скажем, за 0.5 сек на [цвет фона 1].

**Добавлено.**

Я написал xaml код в 
`<windows.resources>`. 
Мой метод заменил на

```
public void PoluchitZnachenie(int value)
        {
            if (value == 0)
            {
                toWhite.Target = Label1; // Здесь он не видит toWhite
                toWhite.Begin();
            }
            if (value == 1)
            {
                toBlack.Target = Label1; // Здесь он не видит toBlack
                toBlack.Begin();
            }
        }

Подскажите, в чём дело? И я в общем думал, чтоб написать метод, возвращающий парметр, т.к. меток будет много или вообще это в гриде будет, что б не метод изменял значения, а возвращал значение (цвет), а этот цвет уже потом становился фоном...
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**

**Ответ:
    (частично сделал,если не считать,что анимации пока нет....)
    http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?tid=929430 /спасибо Esofter**

**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int val;
            if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
            {
                switch (val)
                {
                    case 0:
                        return Brushes.Red;
                    case 1:
                        return Brushes.Green;
                    case 2 :
                        return Brushes.Blue;
                        default:
                        return default(Brushes);
                }
            }

            return default(Brushes);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}

**разметка такая**

<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="284" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Converters:ColorConverter x:Key="colorConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="1"  x:Name="testLabel" Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Content,Converter={StaticResource colorConverter}}"/>
        <Button Width="Auto" Height="100" Content="Change label value" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

ну а кнопка просто меняет значение лейбла

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            testLabel.Content = new Random().Next(3);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не использовать связывание данных, то можно запускать StoryBoard прямо из кода. Пример ниже.

XAML:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="toWhite" Duration="1">
    <ColorAnimation By="Black" To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" />
</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Key="toBlack" Duration="1">
    <ColorAnimation By="White" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" />
</Storyboard>
```

C#:

```
if (value == 0) {
    toWhite.Target = labelX;
    toWhite.Begin();
}
if (value == 1) {
    toBlack.Target = labelX;
    toBlack.Begin();
}
```

Comment: я написал xaml код в 
<windows.resources> 
мой метод заменил на
public void PoluchitZnachenie(int value)
        {
            if (value == 0)
            {
                toWhite.Target = Label1; // Здесь он не видит toWhite
                toWhite.Begin();
            }
            if (value == 1)
            {
                toBlack.Target = Label1; // Здесь он не видит toBlack
                toBlack.Begin();
            }
        }
подскажите, в чём дело?...и я вообщем думал, чтоб написать метод,возвращающий парметр,т.к. меток будет много..или вообще это в гриде будет, что б ячейка п